# Form validation mostly in JavaScript, only security validation server-side

Tags: php, validation, webforms, codeigniter-2

I am building an obscure application which is only available after an involved sign-up process, so submitting malicious data should not occur often.

I use Codeigniter 2.1 to filter all POST variables.  Codeigniter uses the PHP function `mysql_real_escape_string` among other measures to prevent a sql injection attack through POST data.

I do all my validation client-side using JavaScript.  The JavaScript validation runs well.  Of course, a user could use cURL or some other utility to bypass the client-side validation, but the stock PHP validation in Codeigniter should prevent SQL injection, right?

Can I do my validation client-side and trust Codeigniter to protect the database from a SQL injection attack?

Comment: SQL Injection is only one thing to worry about (you are probably safe against that one). You should **always use server-side validation**, Javascript validation is just a convenience feature (Javascript can even be turned off, it's worth nothing when you talk about security). Users can send ANY kind of data, they can manipulate your forms, they don't even need cURL.

Comment: I agree server side validation should be implemented, and Codeigniter does implement a level of server side validation.  The question: does Codeigniter do enough validation, not is any validation required at all.

Comment: Certainly not enough. It can prevent some types of attacks, but you always have to be strict. If you expect a date, only accept a date. If you expect a number, only accept a number. Etc. You should consider client-side validation not existing. Also, filtering and validation is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what codeigniter claims. You can find this in system/core/Security.php file

> Sanitizes data so that Cross Site Scripting Hacks can be prevented. 
>   This function does a fair amount of work but it is extremely thorough,
>   designed to prevent even the most obscure XSS attempts.  Nothing is
>   ever 100% foolproof, of course, but I haven't been able to get
>   anything passed  the filter.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple IMHO. If it uses `mysql_real_escape_string` you are not safe in all cases. See this answer for more information: [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Besides the fact you are not safe it also uses outdated functions for talking to mysql.

Also: you should **always** do server side validation! never ever trust the client side ever!

Comment: I agree server side validation should be implemented, and Codeigniter does implement a level of server side validation.  The question: does Codeigniter do enough validation, not is any validation required at all.